# Dictionary vs nested dictionaries ... for ~7 milion lexical definitions (MULTITEXT v5)

Tags: c#, dictionary, nlp

I'm using lexical resource text file, formatted in MULTITEXT v5 format that actually look like this:

> žvakah    žvakati Vme1s   0   0.000000
>
> žvakahu   žvakati Vme3p   0   0.000000
>
> žvakala   žvakati Vmp-pn  0   0.000000
>
> žvakala   žvakati Vmp-sf  45  0.000081
>
> žvakale   žvakati Vmp-pf  11  0.000020
>
> žvakali   žvakati Vmp-pm  66  0.000119
>
> žvakalo   žvakati Vmp-sn  10  0.000018
>
> žvakan    žvakati Appmsann    0   0.000000
>
> žvakan    žvakati Appmsnn 0   0.000000
>
> žvakan    žvakati Appmsvn 0   0.000000

The format meaning:

> [inflected word]  [lemma form] [grammatical context]  ... and tf-idf info that I don't use

So, in typical scenario I have to match ~5000 of various [inflected word]s to retrieve [lemma form]s and more importantly: [grammatical context]s, where single [inflected word] may actually have more matching lines (like in the case of **žvakan**). The lexical resource to search has about 7 milion lines.

So far, I tried with loading the complete file into List and then running all ~5000 Regexes against each line (List item) using Parallel.ForEach. Regex was used for flexibility to query via [lemma form] or using only part of the word, but for sake of performance I can give up on that. And it took something like 30 minutes to find about 350 entries. So, obviously my approach was completely wrong.

Now I'm thinking to load the complete file into Dictionary where the key would be [inflected word] (so I give up on flexibility) but I wonder:

- Would it make sense (for greater execution time) to nest two dictionaries like this:

> Dictionary<[first letter], Dictionary<[inflected word], List<[definition
>      line]>>>

Would it do any better then loading all into:

> Dictionary<[inflected word], List<[definition line]>>

- Is there some better idea?

I'm not using ConcurrentDictionary since the content is written into data structure only once, before the use starts.

My preference is solely query execution time - RAM seems not to be an issue - with current code I have 19Gb of RAM available, and I have 8 core CPU so any comments on Parallel execution are also welcome.

In case someone wonders: this is a Natural Language Processing application.

Comment: Try a custom hash.  The dictionary key is a hash but may be more efficient to make a custom key for the dictionary using a custom hash when you can group keys that have a lot of letters in common.

Comment: I have no experience with hash, it sounds familiar until you mentioned "custom key" and the grouping stuff. If you have time, please elaborate a bit o if there is some uber example on the net please share the link.

Comment: Nested dictionary is just a substitute for a custom hash table.It a tree structure that is optimized for the data you are using.Dictionaries use binary trees so the number of look ups is log2(x).You can improve performance in strings if you used the letters of the alphabet a get a performance of log26(x).But not all letter of alphabet are used equally so you do not get full performance improvementsIn c# you can use the hash function which packs strings to numbers which improves lookup time.See msdn:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` uses a hash map internally, not a binary tree. A `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, however, _does_ use a binary tree internally. See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/264766/efficiency-of-c-dictionaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my mind again.  Put on a new head.  Decided the best approach is a recursive hashset.  Code need to be upgraded to handle exceptions when a key is not found.  I think this is more efficient because is automatically does the recursion.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] inputs = {
                                  "žvakah žvakati Vme1s 0 0.000000",
                                  "žvakahu žvakati Vme3p 0 0.000000",
                                  "žvakala žvakati Vmp-pn 0 0.000000",
                                  "žvakala žvakati Vmp-sf 45 0.000081",
                                  "žvakale žvakati Vmp-pf 11 0.000020",
                                  "žvakali žvakati Vmp-pm 66 0.000119",
                                  "žvakalo žvakati Vmp-sn 10 0.000018",
                                  "žvakan žvakati Appmsann 0 0.000000",
                                  "žvakan žvakati Appmsnn 0 0.000000",
                                  "žvakan žvakati Appmsvn 0 0.000000"
                              };

            LexicalResource resource = new LexicalResource();

            foreach (string input in inputs)
            {
                resource.Add(input);
            }

            //look up in dictionary
           KeyValuePair<int,decimal> lookup = resource.Get("žvakale žvakati Vmp-pf");

        }
    }

    public class LexicalResource
    {
        public string lexical { get; set; }
        public HashSet<LexicalResource> hash { get; set; }
        public KeyValuePair<int, decimal> value { get; set; }

        public LexicalResource() { }
        public void Add(string lexical)
        {
            string[] tempArray = lexical.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
            AddRecursively(this, tempArray);
        }
        public KeyValuePair<int, decimal> Get(string lexical)
        {
            string[] tempArray = lexical.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
            return GetRecursive(this, tempArray);
        }

        KeyValuePair<int, decimal> GetRecursive(LexicalResource resource, string[] lexicon)
        {
            KeyValuePair<int, decimal> results = new KeyValuePair<int, decimal>();

            int numberChildren = lexicon.Length;
            if (numberChildren == 0)
            {
                results = resource.value;
            }
            else
            {
                LexicalResource child = resource.hash.Where(x => x.lexical == lexicon[0]).FirstOrDefault();
                results = GetRecursive(child, lexicon.Skip(1).ToArray());
            }

            return results;
        }

        void AddRecursively(LexicalResource resource, string[] lexicon)
        {
            lexical = lexicon[0];
            int numberChildren = lexicon.Length;
            if (numberChildren == 2)
            {
                resource.value = new KeyValuePair<int, decimal>(int.Parse(lexicon[0]), decimal.Parse(lexicon[1]));
            }
            else
            {
                if (resource.hash == null)
                {
                    resource.hash = new HashSet<LexicalResource>();
                }
                LexicalResource child = resource.hash.Where(x => x.lexical == lexicon[0]).FirstOrDefault();
                if (child == null)
                {
                    child = new LexicalResource();
                    resource.hash.Add(child);
                }
                AddRecursively(child, lexicon.Skip(1).ToArray());
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll implement and hopefully come back to let you know about results. There are some "mistakes" in your code but I got your point. Thanks bro!

Comment: The improvement of using a recursive hash verses a single hash may be small. Lets say you have a 3 level hash where each level of the hash contains 256 items (2^8),  So when you create a binary tree each tree from root to leaf is 8,  So to find an item you need to do 8 comparisons for each tree and a total of 24 comparisons.  Now if you had a single hash it would be 2^24 which give the same number of comparisons of 24.

Comment: Came back just to thank again and announce that the project went open source, so, if you are in the field, take a look: http://blog.veles.rs/